# How can I install Pygame on a 64-bit win7?

Tags: python, pygame

I have searched the forum and found some related questions, but seems no easy-to-understand answers to me.

I have come to https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads but it only provides 32-bit installer. I am on a 64-bit Win7, which is already installed Python 3.3.2. How can I install Pygame in this case? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried installing with the 32-bit installer? Often it'll still work. If not, you may have to downgrade Python to 2.7 and then get the 64-bit Python 2.7 Pygame installer.

Comment: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ is your one-stop shop for 64-bit versions of many Python libraries.  Pygame is available there.

Comment: @BrenBarn, OMG, you save me! What a coool site! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) contains non-official binaries of many Python packages for 32 and 64 bit versions of Windows, and it is also mentioned in the [downloads section of Pygame.org](http://pygame.org/download.shtml). The downloads for Pygame are [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame).

Comment: @Dennisboys I have seen the comment of BrenBarn after posting my answer, and I think his contribution was more useful than mine's ;) Glad it helped anyway.